# curl an image header returns two HTTP request

Tags: macos, curl

I'm just familiarizing a bit more with cURL and I don't know why (on a mac) doing a curl to return the HTTP headers of an image, terminal returns two blocks, the fist with the current image information, the second of domain root?

What's the point?
Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Please show us details. Like the command line you used and the full headers send and received back (curl --trace-ascii might be your friend).

Comment: that was a simple curl -I URL_of_an_image